# I want to remove item in the list if that item already added to table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding data into the table after submitting so what my task is I need to check any item that adds to the table mean that is present in the table that  that select name object  will remove from **Select Name** I am trying to remove that list using **filteredArray** function check that code below but it not working properly so if that name is present in the table then that name will not show in **select name TextFiled** need to remove that already select and added in the table

```
export default function App() {
  const nameList = [
    {
      selectName: "onee",
      selectAge: "18",
      location: "nagpur"
    },
    {
      selectName: "two",
      selectAge: "20",
      location: "pune"
    },
    {
      selectName: "three",
      selectAge: "20",
      location: "mumbai"
    }
  ];
  const [teamdata, setTeamData] = React.useState([]);

  const AssignSearchesForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      selectName: "",
      selectAge: "",
      location: ""
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setTeamData([values, ...teamdata]);
    }
  });
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedName = e.target.value;
    const name = nameList.find((data) => data.selectName === selectedName);
    const newOptions = Object.values(name).reduce((optionList, key) => {
      optionList.push({ value: key, label: key });
      return optionList;
    }, []);
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("selectName", selectedName);
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("selectAge", newOptions[1]?.value || "");
    AssignSearchesForm.setFieldValue("location", newOptions[2]?.value || "");
  };
  let filteredArray = nameList.filter(
    (e) => e.selectName !== teamdata.map((data) => data.selectName)
  );
  console.log("filteredArray", filteredArray);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <TextField
            sx={{ minWidth: 150 }}
            select
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Select Name"
            name="selectName"
            size="small"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={AssignSearchesForm.values.selectName}
          >
            {filteredArray?.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.selectName} value={option.selectName}>
                {option.selectName}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="location"
            name="location"
            size="small"
            {...AssignSearchesForm.getFieldProps("location")}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              AssignSearchesForm.handleSubmit();
            }}
            variant="contained"
          >
            Add
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Table teamdata={teamdata} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking:

```
  let filteredArray = nameList.filter(
    (e) => !teamdata.some(data => data.selectName === e.selectName)
  );
```